# Magento 2: How to set default value of quantity in new product page

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, product-attribute

I am new developer of Magento 2.

Is Magento provided a way to set default value of quantity in admin new product page?
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution:

> your_module_dir/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <modal name="advanced_inventory_modal">
        <fieldset name="stock_data">
            <field name="qty">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
        </fieldset>
    </modal>
</form>
```

Don't forget clear cache. I hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

> Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="defaultQtyModifier" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\DefaultQtyModifier</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/DefaultQtyModifier.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;

class DefaultQtyModifier extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
    * @var LocatorInterface
    */
    private $locator;

    /**
     * DefaultQtyModifier constructor.
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $data
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        $model = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $modelId = $model->getId();

        if (!isset($data[$modelId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['quantity_and_stock_status']['qty'])) {
            $data[$modelId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['quantity_and_stock_status']['qty'] = 'Enter Your Qty';
        }

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $meta
     * @return array
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        return $meta;
    }
}
```