# Magento 2: How to set disable for "Enable Product" by default in new product page

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I ask another similar question before ask this question.

[Magento 2: How to set default value of quantity in new product page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197680/magento-2-how-to-set-default-value-of-quantity-in-new-product-page)

However, I cannot set "disable" to "Enable Product" field by default. I try to find the xml file to add

```
<item name="value" xsi:type="string">1</item>
```

However, I cannot find where it can put.
Also, I try to change the meta for this field.

```
$meta["product-details"]["children"]["container_status"]["children"]["status"]["arguments"]["data"]["config"]["default"] = "2";
```

After add this to my modifer. It still show "Enable" by default.

Is I do something wrong about set it to disable?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your database and change the default value to `status` attribute to 0 instead of 1.

You can find the attribute in `eav_attribute` table.
By default it will be having id as 97

You can also change the default value in admin. Go to store-> attribute -> product-> search for status attribute. And change its default value

Comment: sorry, I tried and it still show enable...

Comment: Try doing reindexing and cleaning cache