# Set custom default qty when creating new product Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0, qty, default-values

I need Quantity field to be filled with custom value when creating new product in admin. I have already tried modificators (haven't figured out how to set data for new product with `modifyData($data)` and 
[this answer seems to be not working anymore.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/197680/magento-2-how-to-set-default-value-of-quantity-in-new-product-page). Is there some way to do so?

Making an observer on event `catalog_product_new_action` and `$observer->getEvent()->getProduct()->setQty(%number%)` doesnt work either.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own modifier pool in your custom extension to achieve this.
Following files would do the work.

> etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="defaultQtyModifier" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\DefaultQtyModifier</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

> Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/DefaultQtyModifier.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;

class DefaultQtyModifier extends AbstractModifier
{
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        $model = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $modelId = $model->getId();

        if (!isset($data[$modelId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['quantity_and_stock_status']['qty'])) {
            $data[$modelId][self::DATA_SOURCE_DEFAULT]['quantity_and_stock_status']['qty'] = 12;
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        return $meta;
    }
}
```

Here, instead of **12**, you can defined your custom qty number.

Replace Vendor and Module with your original Vendor and Module name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I almost had it myself, but it wouldn't work until I moved `di.xml` to `adminhtml/di.xml`

Comment: You're welcome !!!